# DevOps | TeamCity | Trouble building .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, teamcity, devops

I'm relatively new to DevOps, been tasked with getting .NET core apps to build in TeamCity, and then to deploy in Octopus.

I meet all the prerequisites - .NET core plugin installed, SDK on the agent, etc.

When trying the project.sln file as my project file, my build completes successfully, but with no artifacts.

When pointing my build steps to the project.csproj file, I get a "MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist."

Any advise on getting this to build would be much appreciated.
I've been combing the interwebs but haven't found the fix yet.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What do you mean by "no artifacts"? What you have in General Settings -> Artifact Paths in TeamCity?

Comment: Did you check the directory where artefacts not found?

Comment: So, the way I've been trained is - once a build completes successfully, it should show some 'artifacts', which to my understanding are the items we're trying to deploy (usually .nuget packages). With my .NET core build, it's empty. Under General, 'Artifact Paths' is empty. However, we do have a 'CustomParam.TFS.SolutionPath' parameter set pointing to the TFS directory where the .sln file resides.

Answer (score 0):

I had same confusions as yours, so i took time to do few courses and would suggest you to do the same, otherwise you will get stuck again. You can have a look at the course here: https://www.tetratutorials.com/p/teamcity-continuous-integration-devops-with-java-and-net . This will give you a clear understanding of your troubles. I even got my certification from her, hence suggesting.